# How do I split a 1170 pixels grid into 8 boxes?

Tags: css

I need to split a 1170 grid into 8 boxes of `X` each with each box having the same amount of padding on the left and right. I can't seem to get it right :(

I managed to do `134 x 8 pixels` and then a gutter of `14` each but that doesn't work because then the first and last box wouldn't have the same padding.

Comment: Can you add your markup and css

Comment: Instead of doing the hard calculations yourself, why not use CSS flexbox?

Comment: Use any grid system and first split it in two, then put four containers in each?

Comment: Make each box 146.25px wide in total.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `calc`

```
padding: 7px;
width: calc(12.5% - 14px);
```

More on [Calc](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) at W3Schools.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use flexbox, you can get even spacing in only a few lines instead of calculating by hand. The best resource I've found for flexbox is https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, `flex` makes it easy.

`+` selector will help to manage visually even `padding`

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;/* block level */
  width:1170px;/* any values here or none */
  height:100px;/* whatever: demo purpse*/
  margin:auto;
  background:lightgray;/* whatever: demo purpse*/
}
.flex div {
  flex:1;/* sprays child evenly to fill whole space*/
  padding:1em;
  background:gray;
  background-clip:content-box;/*show box minus padding area */
}
.flex div + div {/* make padding visually even */
  padding-left:0;
}

div div {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content/* it's not text-align*/:center;
  }
/* not just sure if that would be fine ? */
.flex:hover div {
  padding:21px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px white
  }
```

```html
<div class=flex>
  <div>average 128px each</div>
  <div>width for content</div>
  <div>is less or more</div>
  <div>according to font-size</div>
  <div>padding is 1em</div>
  <div>but could be</div>
  <div>static units</div>
  <div>such as pixels</div>
</div
```

you do not want to use `flex` because you (unfortunate you) run IE8 ? `display:table` + `table-layout:fixed` will do the job for you

```css
.flex {
  display: table;
  /* block level */
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* sprays child evenly if no width is specified*/
  width: 1170px;
  /* any values here or none */
  height: 100px;
  /* whatever: demo purpse*/
  margin: auto;
  background: lightgray;
  /* whatever: demo purpse*/
}
.flex div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  background: gray;
  background-clip: content-box;
  /*show box minus padding area */
}
.flex div + div {
  /* make padding visually even */
  padding-left: 0;
}
div div {
  vertical-align:middle;
 text-align : center;
}
/* not just sure if that would be fine ? */

.flex:hover div {
  padding: 21px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white
}
```

```html
<div class=flex>
  <div>average 128px each</div>
  <div>width for content</div>
  <div>is less or more</div>
  <div>according to font-size</div>
  <div>padding is 1em</div>
  <div>but could be</div>
  <div>static units</div>
  <div>such as pixels</div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my jsFiddle here wouldn't work but I got eight columns working here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoyEme

Make two half columns then put four columns in each of those for a total of eight.

Code:

```css
.container,
.row,
.col-lg-6 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

div {border: 1px dotted red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        ONE
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```